# How to use custom CSS in Magento 2.0?

Tags: magento-2.0

I need to add custom CSS in Magento 2.0. How can we add made changes in CSS?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

We can add custom css in magento2

link : https://community.magento.com/t5/Theming-Layout-Design-Questions/How-to-add-a-custom-CSS-file-in-Magento-1-9-2-4-CE/td-p/50654

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the stylesheets you include should be available for all store pages. To achieve this, include your CSS in default_head_blocks.xml of the Magento_Theme module, which defines the default  page section for all Magento pages.

The recommended way to do this is adding an extending default_head_blocks.xml in your theme, and including the required stylesheets in this file.

Path Example : app/design/frontend/Testthemes/demo3/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml (This path not present then copy file from default file to your theme.)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/youe-style-name.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do add custom css you will have to follow these given steps:

**Step1-** Make sure that you set your Magento application to the developer mode.

**Step2-** Add the following folders to your custom theme

```
app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme] / Magento_Theme / layout

app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme] / web / css
```

Create the following files:

```
app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme] / Magento_Theme / layout / default_head_blocks.xml
app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme] / web / css / local-m.css
app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme] / web / css / local-l.css
```

place this code within `default_head_blocks.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <head>
    <css src="css/local-m.css" />
    <css src="css/local-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
  </head>
</page>
```

**Step3-** Apply your theme: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html

**Step4-** Deploy static resources (using SSH): php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy